# Google Maps API - Text on top of map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**QUESTION:** Is it possible to create text with Google Maps API that hovers over the window in a fixed position even when you are zooming in/out or panning?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:**
I already know that infowindows are possible with the following code:

```
var contentString = "<div>Hello!</div>";
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
});
marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

But the previous info-window requires a marker, and markers as far as I know can only have fixed positions on the map (I couldn't find out how to place a marker in the center of the screen and keep it there even when the user moves the map around)

Does anyone know of a way to place the text in the middle of the map? It could be with info windows or another methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a InfoWindow you could just set `visible: false` for the marker and then change the position of the marker whenever the center position of the map changes:

```
/* Invisible marker for the InfoWindow */
textmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    visible: false
});

/* Center change handler to always center the marker */
map.addListener('center_changed', function() {
    textmarker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
});

/* adding the info window */
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Your Text can be placed here"
    });
infowindow.open(map, textmarker);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7rtsv2y4/

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the text just sits above the map in a static position, you can do this with CSS:

```
<div class="map-container">
 <-- google map div here -->
 <div class="textbox">Static Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.map-container {
  position: relative;
}

.textbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%:
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1000;
}
```